# Xamarin SQLite using LINQ

Tags: c#, android, linq, sqlite, xamarin

I got a sqlite table in xamarain (native android / pcl):

```
    [Table("Customer")]
    public class Customer
    {
         [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public Address Address{ get; set; }
    }
```

"Address" represents a second table.

1) Is it possible to automatically create the "Address" Table when I call

```
connection.CreateTable<CustomerDto>();
```

because it is it's dependency?

2) Is it possible to use a LINQ expression which automatically maps the correct "Address" to this "Customer?

Answer (score 1):

In my .NET Standard library I'm using:

- "sqlite-net": "1.0.8"
- "sqlite-net-pcl": "1.3.1"

My approach was to create "initial state models" of all the tables, marked as abstract (so there is no risk that somebody could instantiate them), defining only the fields necessary in the database and the primary keys (GUID in my case), used only to create tables at the beginning. Following modification to the data structures always with ALTER instructions.
In another namespace a duplication of all the models, this time with getters/setters and other utilities, and I used these as "real models".

For representing linked models I used a field as Id and another one as model (refreshed when necessary):

```
public int IdAddress { get; set; }
[Ignore]
public Address Address { get; set; }
```

I don't think sqlite-net can do what you are asking because it's a very lightweight orm, and even if it could I prefer don't automate too much because of my past experiences with Hibernate.

https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

https://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlite-net

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should look at using Entity Framework because that will allow you to use LINQ with SQLite. The standard library on the web (not Entity framework) is very light and doesn't have much functionality for the ORM like functionality you are looking for.

If you're looking for a more lightweight library, you can use this, but it will not allow you to write LINQ expressions without writing your own ORM:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/SQLite.Net.Standard